re-render input component not losing focus when re-rendering
I present two different ways to render an input component;
E.g.1
function myComponent(){                 
const [st, setSt] = useState('');       
                                        
return <div>                            
{Math.random()}                         
<input value={st}                      
  onChange={e=>setSt(e.target.value)/>  
</div> 

E.g. 2
 function StateHelper() {
  const [st, setSt] = useState("");

  return { context: { st, setSt } };
}

function MyHelper(prop) {
  const ActualComponent = prop.capture;

  return <ActualComponent />;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const { context } = StateHelper();

  const capturedComponent = () => (
    <input
      value={context.st}
      onChange={(e) => {
        context.setSt(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );

  return <MyHelper capture={capturedComponent} />;
}

Runnable Fiddle For e.g. 2
I seem to be confused on one of the fundamentals.
On e.g. 1, when I type, I don't lose focus on the input component.
On e.g. 2, on each letter typed, I lose focus.
On both of these examples, Math.random() changes, so they both re-render.
I don't know what's the difference, and why I keep losing focus on e.g. 2 ?
I'm trying to follow e.g. 2 as it helps me manage my code better, but can't seem to understand it. What am I not understanding about react component re-rendering and how can I fix it?

Your examples aren't valid React in the least. Please reformat this so they're sequentially instead of side-by-side, too.

I tested that (I had to fix some syntax) and it works, not focus lost. I think you created your component inside another component. Also, adding code like that is very inconvenient because it can't be copied

Please also show how you're using these components – since they're named myComponent instead of MyComponent, you'd have to be going through extra hoops to begin with (you can't do <myComponent />, since JSX interprets myComponent as the name of an intrinsic element).

noted, I'm updating the code asap

I' m trying to add a fiddle to replicate the issue

@AKX , I updated the code with runnable fiddle, seems the e.g. 2 was misleading

@Konrad , it seems, my e.g. 2 was misleading, I added a runnable fiddle

sorry for the inconvenience to everyone, seems I made a mistake making a minimal example

Same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715158/react-hooks-input-loses-focus-when-1-character-is-typed-in

Your const capturedComponent = () => ( is an inner function whose identity changes with each invocation of the component declaring it.
That makes React think that the component is not the same one that it rendered the last go, so it will unmount the old one and remount the new one (even if they might be identical in output), which in turn causes the focus loss on the input element.
See the documentation for the React ESlint rule for this issue for more details.

what about in example 1? Why do we not lose focus even when the entire component is re-rendered?

@BumbleBee rerendering is not a problem. Remounting is. The component in the second example is destroyed and created again every time you press a key

seems a good read: https://ferreira.io/posts/re-mounting-vs-re-rendering

@AKX, the link you've provided, mentions a solution to not use memoized function to be able to capture a value of a variable, then I'm not getting how to capture a value of the variable when you have to say, persist the state at the page level? In above, I can't move StateHelper() outside  because I want the state to persist in , do you have any suggestions?

You'd move capturedComponent outside MyComponent and pass st and setSt as props to it (or use the React context API in more complex cases).

but, in above case, you can't really do that. Captured component has captured values, and you'd then have to add logic to MyHelper and.... well basically do prop drilling
